# You Don't Know JS: Async and Performance - cooperative concurrency?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous

Kyle example is about chunking data (when is so big) by asynchronous events and make events interleave in the event loop queue, that part i couldn't get:

**The example from book:**

```
var res = [];
// `response(..)` receives array of results from the Ajax call
function response(data) {

   var chunk = data.splice( 0, 1000 );

   res = res.concat(

    chunk.map( function(val){
      return val * 2;
    } )
  );

  if (data.length > 0) {

    setTimeout( function(){
        response( data );
    }, 0 );
  }
}
// ajax(..) is some arbitrary Ajax function given by a library
ajax( "http://some.url.1", response );
ajax( "http://some.url.2", response );
```

I could not get that part, my mind can not accept that this could make code perform better, wouldn't that cause data from two arrays to interleave, or i just don't understand how event loop work??

Comment: There's only one array...so what is your question?

Comment: no two arrays as you see in the ajax calls ??

Comment: my question is under the code snippet, i do not know how this is supposed to enhance performance and doesn't cause data conflict?

Comment: No, there is one array `res` and multiple calls to `response` will in effect keep adding to it. It does nothing to enhance the performance *of the code itself*. In fact, it will cause that operation to take longer. How it helps is that it breaks up the long-running operation and gives other code (like event handlers) a chance to run.

Comment: What i mean is, we now have two arrays of data, and chunking them with asynchronous events which is not guaranteed in ordering, may push some parts of array of data from url1 with some parts of array of data from url2..or i am just stupid??

Comment: Ah ok. Yes, you are correct that the order may get screwed up. As for the performance aspect, see my earlier comment. It's really about breaking up blocking operations so they... well, don't block so much. I think it was probably meant to be an example rather than production-ready code.

Comment: that part i can't understand as well, logically i can't see this may enhance performance, isn't event loop call functions subsequently?? and this would  make no difference with chunking data??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201600/discussion-between-jared-smith-and-saher-elgendy).

Comment: Quote "the interleaving onto the event loop queue will give us a much **more responsive** (performant) site/app". _Performant_  should go in quotes. The approach could make the app **look** more performant by making it more responsive.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko i see now, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you are correct that there is a potential for misordering of data with multiple ajax calls (and it was very astute of you to notice, +1), with the code posted you could get:

1. ajax call 1 starts
2. ajax call 1 finishes
3. append the first 1000 elements from call 1
4. ajax call 2 starts
5. append the next 1000 elements from call 1
6. ajax call 2 finishes
7. append the first 1000 elements from call 2
8. append the next 1000 elements from call 1

As for the performance aspect of the question, remember that 'performance' isn't just one thing. If by performance you mean 'how long does this block of code take to run' then chunking will lead to worse performance. But this is frontend. 'Performance' is really about user experience, and your Javascript code runs on the main thread. If you have a 10 second operation then your UI is unresponsive for 10 seconds. If you chunk it then the user can still interact with the page while it's running, even if it takes a little longer to complete.

Comment: @SaherElgendy glad to help.